# UIKeyboardNotifications not being called

Tags: ios, ios8, uikeyboard

I'm running ios8b4, and I have some code that registers for keyboard notifications to animate my view.

```
Class KeyboardAdjuster

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)unregisterForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

They are called in a view controller's appearance methods. self.keyboardAdjuster is not nil (verified), and I can step into the register methods and those 2 notifications are supposedly registered. There is no call to unregister ever until the view controller disappears.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.keyboardAdjuster registerForKeyboardNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(searchEvent:) name:[SCWebSearchEvent identifier] object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:[SCWebSearchEvent identifier] object:nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [self.keyboardAdjuster unregisterForKeyboardNotifications];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

In addition, my selectors get called in the iOS simulator perfectly whenever a textview or textfield get called, but for some reason, when running on my device, they never get called. Is there anything else that I need to do when running on a device vs. simulator?

Comment: Where you call this method(registerForKeyboardNotifications) and (unregisterForKeyboardNotifications)

Comment: I call them from my viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear methods. They are being properly called when I debugged, but the notifications are never being sent when my keyboard pops up.

Comment: @SunnyShah is asking the right question. Where are you calling `registerForKeyboardNotifications` and `unregisterForKeyboardNotifications`? Maybe unregister is being called too. Try logging in the methods to make sure.

Comment: Also, this code is working perfectly fine on simulator. It is only when I build it on my device that those notifications are not being sent. There are no code changes between the builds for simulator and device. This code, which hasn't been changed, also worked for ios8 beta 3. Just wondering if something changed that I need to incorporate for iOS8 beta 4.

Comment: Having same issue on iOS 8.4. UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification is working and I made a workaround using this for now.